How to modify query converting DATEDIFF to Oracle accepted syntax?
I have a query which calculates date difference calculated in minutes excluding weekends but syntax doesn't work in Oracle, please help.
SELECT
(   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, create_date, status_date)
    - ( DATEDIFF(wk, create_date,status_date)*(2*24*60)
        -- End on Sunday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, status_date)  = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,status_date),status_date) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, create_date) = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,create_date),create_date) ELSE 0 END)
        -- End on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, status_date)  = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,status_date),status_date) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, create_date) = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,create_date),create_date) ELSE 0 END)
    )
) as min_diff 
FROM TABLE_Name


Adapting my answer for number of business days difference between two dates to minutes, you can calculate it by:

counting the number of full weeks from the start of the ISO week (always midnight on Monday) containing the start-date to the start of the ISO week containing the end-date as a multiple of 5-day periods.
Add the number of fractional days from the start of the ISO week containing the end-date to the actual end-date (ignoring weekends).
Subtract the number of fractional days from the  from the start of the ISO week containing the start-date to the actual start-date (ignoring weekends).
Multiply the total by 24 to get hours and 60 to get minutes.

Like this:
SELECT TO_CHAR( start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS "("DY")"') AS start_date,
       TO_CHAR( end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS "("DY")"') AS end_date,
       ROUND(
         (
           ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
         + LEAST( end_date - TRUNC( end_date,   'IW' ), 5 )
         - LEAST( start_date - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
         ) * 24 * 60,
         2
       ) AS Num_Week_Day_Minutes
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-04-12' + INTERVAL '23:59:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2024-04-15' + INTERVAL '00:01:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-05' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2024-04-15' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-14' + INTERVAL '23:59:00' HOUR TO SECOND,
       DATE '2024-04-15' + INTERVAL '00:01:00' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL

Outputs:



START_DATE
END_DATE
NUM_WEEK_DAY_MINUTES




2024-04-12 23:59:00 (FRI)
2024-04-15 00:01:00 (MON)
2


2024-04-05 00:00:00 (FRI)
2024-04-15 00:00:00 (MON)
8640


2024-04-14 23:59:00 (SUN)
2024-04-15 00:01:00 (MON)
1



fiddle
